# sum columns from two tables into third table with two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, aggregate-functions

I'm fairly new to MySQL.
I'm trying to take a summarized data(float) from two columns in two different tables and create a third table with total of two columns and one row which is the sum total ...
here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT SUM(column_from_table1),
SUM(column_from_table2) 
From table1, table2
```

It gives me back 2 columns with the wrong `numbers(sum)`.
Where I'm getting it wrong?
If you need more data in order to help me please let me know.

Comment: You can edit your question, including the title.

Comment: thanks Honza, i'm quite slow today

Comment: Your problem is that when you select `from table1, table2`, an implicit [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) is done (try `select * from table1, table2` to see what that means). If you want to sum just the records in table1 or table2, use 2 separate queries. Also, it's not a good practice to store the sum in a separate table, it's not usually neccessary and you are duplicating the data.

Comment: I forget to mention, this is only to display the data in a visual table (from a wordpress plugin that reads MySQL language).
I'm not inserting any data just reading.

Comment: And you need it in single query? You can use `UNION`: `SELECT SUM(column_from_table1) FROM table1 UNION SELECT SUM(column_from_table2) FROM table2`. Only, it will not return 2 columns, but 2 rows.

Comment: I've tried that before, it gives the correct sum but one column and two rows as you said. (I need two columns and one row in a single query)
I'm kinda feeling like annoying you right now. 
Thanks for helping me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you select `from table1, table2`, an implicit [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) is made. Either use 2 queries, or  use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(column_from_table1) AS SUM1,
       (SELECT SUM(column_from_table2) FROM table2) AS SUM2
From table1
```